# Lubuntu not connect to internet after placing the static address

Tags: networking, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu. (`/etc/network/interfaces`) to change the IP of my network card so all remaining static as follows

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.1.110 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.1.1 # router ip
```

I have no connection to Internet when I put the static address by dhcp while if I?

Comment: Hi @user6260009, can you run ifconfig and post the results of that into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you need to have the following entry. Most likely, your PC is not getting the DNS server. make this entry below the gateway line. It should look like this.

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.110
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
**dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2 192.168.1.1**

default DNS are 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS), or 4.2.2.2 and the 192.168.1.1 is the router IP which ideally should be the DNS for your PC. You could also add the DNS servers of your service provider in front of the router IP separating it with a single space.

Hope this helps
Regards